# Can you attack Bigby's Icy Grasp

Tags: dnd-4e

It's all in the question. Is it possible to target Bigby's Icy Grasp. If so, what are it's defenses, hp, etc.?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### No, Bigby's Icy Grasp cannot be attacked.

From the PHB, p161:

> **Bigby's Icy Grasp**
> Daily - Arcane, Cold, Conjuration, Implement

Note that it has the *Conjuration* keyword.

From the RC, p117:

> ... Normally, a conjuration cannot be attacked or physically affected. ...

So effects created by powers with the Conjuration keyword can't be attacked unless the power explicitly says they can.

The Bigby's Icy Grasp power doesn't say that it *can* be attacked, therefore it *can't* be attacked. For instance, compare it to the Wall of Ice level 15 wizard daily power (also from the PHB), which also has the Conjuration keyword but explicitly describes how the conjuration can be attacked.